# How to execute multiple executable together

Tags: command-line, executable

I want to execute the below shown executable together using the .sh file.
I am trying as shown below.But this executing one after another. Please guide me the changes I should make to execute them together.

[image]

### Edit

[image]
Putting & means that these executables will execute almost together.

Comment: If your `complete_user_process[1-7]` doesn't need input, you can put each into the background by suffixing each line with "`&`", as explained in `man bash`.

Comment: Hi @waltinator, does putting & means that above processes are executing together as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash job control "process &" to manage what is running in the background. Then use [wait](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait) to await the final process to finish.